# Less than 6 month's passport validity transit through Doha

Tags: transit, passports, paperwork, australian-citizens, doh

Is it possible to transit through Doha Airport (not leaving the airport) with less than 6 months validity on your passport?  If entry is permitted at destination location (Sydney)

Comment: The last part of the question can only be answered baswd on which passport your are travelling with.

Comment: Suppose you are traveling on say, London - Doha - Sydney, you won't be allowed to board from London because of 6 Month validity issue, unless you are a citizen of Australia. So, citizenship is important.

Comment: @AnishSheela Absolutely wrong; when transiting most countries, incl. Qatar, their entry requirements don't apply whatsoever. And Australia only requires passports to be valid on arrival.

Answer (score 4):

What Qatar requires for entry has zero relevance in this, as you're not entering that country.

As stated in TIMATIC, the database used at check-in, Australia only requires a valid passport for any and all passenger categories.

As such, you can do this trip with no problems.